# Valgrind error even in a simple "Hello World" program (std::cout)

Tags: c++, std, valgrind

I get some valgrind errors originating from `std::`. So I striped down my program to the very simple "Hello World" example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;  // (Line 8)
}
```

But I still get the following error:

```
==1311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1311==    at 0x1004E8C3F: _platform_memchr$VARIANT$Haswell (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib)
==1311==    by 0x1002DCB96: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1311==    by 0x1002DD0AA: fwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1311==    by 0x100029D29: std::__1::__stdoutbuf<char>::overflow(int) (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==1311==    by 0x10001F91C: std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, long) (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==1311==    by 0x100001C88: std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) (streambuf:360)
==1311==    by 0x1000016A6: std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) (ostream:743)
==1311==    by 0x1000012C3: std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (ostream:882)
==1311==    by 0x100001257: main (main.cpp:8)
==1311==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==1311==    at 0x100029CD8: std::__1::__stdoutbuf<char>::overflow(int) (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
```

Commands to compile and run valgrind (on OSX Yosemite):

```
g++ -o main main.cpp --std=c++0x -O0 -g
valgrind --log-file=vg1.txt --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./main
```

I'm not sure how to deal with this error:

1. I guess it's really not my fault. But could there be something wrong with the configuration of these libraries?
2. Do I have to worry about the error? If not, would there be a way to filter such errors?

Comment: Duplicate is a C question but clearly the same underlying issue